# Django post_save() signal to register new user

Tags: django, django-views

Below is the createprofileview class-based view to register a new user and also to create the profile of that user at the same time.

```
class CreateProfileView(CreateView):
model = Profile

 def post(self, request):
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid(): 
        user_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home', args=[]))
        messages.warning(request, 'Something went wrong in Venter, please try again')

 def get(self, request):
    user_form = UserForm()
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, './mysite/registration.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

I have used post_save() signal along with my Profile model as follows:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(
    User, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    primary_key = True
  )
  organisation_name = models.ForeignKey(
    Organisation,
    on_delete= models.CASCADE,
    null=True,
  )
  profile_picture = models.ImageField(
    upload_to='Organisation/Employee Profile Picture/%Y/%m/%d/', 
    null=True,
    blank=True,
  )
  phone_number = models.CharField(
    blank=True, 
    max_length=10
  )
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username 

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  instance.profile.save()
```

**However, the user gets created and saved, but its profile details do not get saved.** 
I am unsure how to tweak the signals function suitable to my requirements of registering a new user and also creating their profile at the same time.

Here is the forms.py:

```
  class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

  class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
      model = Profile
      fields = ('organisation_name', 'phone_number', 'profile_picture')
```

Comment: Are the signals triggered after the user creation ?

Comment: I don't think so, because the profile is still empty for each new user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point of having a profile creation signal, because you are already having a `ProfileForm` to get the Profile Data. I think you can get rid of the profile signals and update the view to save the profile form directly. Like this:

```
if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
     user = user_form.save()
     profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
     profile.user = user
     profile.save()

     # rest of the code
```

#### Update

*from comments*

You need to set your password in User object. You can do that in your form's `save` method by overriding like this(using [set_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) method):

```
class UserForm(...):
    ...
    def save(self, **kwargs):
       user = super(UserForm, self).save(commit=False)
       password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
       user.set_password(password)
       user.save()
       return user
```

Comment: the profile details are now getting saved, but my user is unable to log into the website with its username and password, when I checked in my database, the passwords are open, they are not sha-1 key encrypted.

Comment: @Simran As you have not shared any user form related code, its hard to provide exact solution. But I have shared a way how you can do this in the Answer. Please check it.